# KeyError: 'cross' when trying to do cartesian product with merge()

Tags: python, pandas, cartesian-product

I have this line of code:

```
all_task_food_rescuer_combinations = task_data.merge(food_rescuer_data, how='cross')
```

It is giving me this error message:

```
KeyError: 'cross'
```

I don't have any columns named 'cross'. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Update: I swapped that line of code with these lines:

```
task_data['key'] = 1
food_rescuer_data['key'] = 1
all_task_food_rescuer_combinations = pd.merge(task_data, food_rescuer_data, on ='key').drop("key", 1)
```

I don't have the error now, but I'm still curious why my first approach didn't work. That line of code is straight from the documentation.

Comment: 'cross' is new to [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in pandas v1.2.0. Are you using an older version of pandas?

Comment: otherwise, please provide the [full traceback](/realpython.com/python-traceback) and ideally a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help debug.

Comment: Oh I see. I just checked and I have v1.1.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `'cross'` to `how=` but it is `New in version 1.2.0` so consider updating your pandas to a newer version.

Otherwise you can create an artificial column so that every row would have the same value in both dataframes:

```py
left = task_data.assign(key=1)
right = food_rescuer_data(key=1)
left.merge(right, on='key').drop('key', 1)
```